# $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, but is it a non-trivial proper subgroup?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, but I don't know if it's a non-trivial proper subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$. I understand how to determine a subgroups when they are not matrices, but I don't understand it when they are. I also know non-trivial means not the identity set and proper means it's a proper subset of the given group. I'm just confused how you determine these with matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

To show it's nontrivial, can you find an element $A\in SL_2 (\mathbb R)$ which is not the identity matrix? (That is, can you find a matrix with determinant 1 but is not the identity?)

To show it's proper, can you find a matrix $A$ which is in $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ but not in $SL_2(\mathbb R)$? (That is, can you find an invertible matrix which has determinant $\neq 1$?)